# Chrome vs Safari iPhone Bootstrap Issue

Tags: html, css, iphone, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am facing weird issue when working with Bootstrap and Html Page. It is working fine using chrome and all other devices except iphone Safari.

*My **Code** is working* [here](http://percmind.com/emovey_ui_2/sixth.html)

So far what i understand is, it is not executing media quires. I am not able to understand why whereas it is working perfect for all others.

Initially i was using meta tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0">
```

**My Actual result is: Which is perfect on Chrome.**

[image]

**But rendering in Safari on iPhone**.

[image]

When I added meta

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale = 1.0,maximum-scale = 1.0" />
```

It started to look like,

[image]